# Capacitors choice for MHz resonance circuit

Tags: power-electronics, components, high-frequency, wireless-charging

I am implementing a resonance circuit (for wireless charging) in MHz frequency (\$5-10~MHz\$) , and now, I am looking for suitable capacitors. The peak voltages and current through the capacitors are around \$350~V\$, and \$12~A\$. I know that I must go with low loss capacitors (\$NP0\$). In addition to the voltage rating, ESR will set a thermal limit for maximum current.

But I am not sure what are the critical parameters that I should look for.

For example, consider the following two from the same manufacturer with very similar specs:

> [VJ1808A101KXHAT4X](https://www.mouser.fi/ProductDetail/Vishay-Vitramon/VJ1808A101KXHAT4X?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs0AnBnWHyRQB4XKvGDYITzWppblgbiArg%3D) MLCC, SMD/SMT 1808 NP0 100PF 3KV 10%
>
> [VJ1111D101JXRAJ](https://www.mouser.fi/ProductDetail/Vishay-Vitramon/VJ1111D101JXRAJ?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs0AnBnWHyRQID2xuQsFd1GVlf%252BdhYul%2FEKGH9mTW4H8Q%3D%3D)   MLCC - SMD/SMT 1111 100pF 1500V C0G 5% HI FREQ

[image]

My feeling is that the first one may not suitable for the high-power application, but all look similar in the specifications. Just that the former has more information about the ESR and Q-factor in the datasheet, and also specifically mentioned that it is suitable for RF power applications.

But all the MLCC (NP0) manufactures do not have this information.

**In general**, (Not specifically for the above two. Two examples are just for a comparison) What should I look for when deciding if a capacitor suit for high-power application (even if it is NP0 and sufficient voltage rating). For now, I am paying attention to the size of the cap.

Additional info: as the application is a high-Q resonance circuit, harmonics will be very small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These caps are very generic, especially with the C0G/NP0 dielectric.  (Note that C0G and NP0 are different labels for the same dielectric.)  The lower DF implies a lower ESR for the VJ1111 part.  Its geometry will give it a lower ESL as well; although that's not likely to be that much of an issue at 5-10MHz, I don't know what kind of harmonics you're dealing with.  It's got a better tolerance and is slightly smaller.  I'd go with the 1111 over the 1808 based only on this information, but you know your requirements best.

Comment: @ChistobalPolychronopolis, Thanks, yes, I am quite certain that I will choose 11111 over 1808, if I were to choose between this two. But my question here is that In general, what are the critical parameters I should look for?

Comment: To answer that, I'd have to see the schematics and requirements.  With the current you're looking at, I'd be most focused on low DF or ESR (whichever way the cap is specified).

Comment: Most datasheets do not have ESR. What is the relation between DF and ERS? Not sure what is the threshold for low DF. 0.1% is already small.

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/basic_concepts/capacitance/esr-dissipation-factor-loss-tangent-q.php

Comment: You can find frequency dependent ESR data on Kemet capacitors using http://ksim.kemet.com/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Post the ESR values you have.

"Dissipation factor 0.1%" on a 4 kVA power flow suggests 4W loss to me.

What will that do to a 1808? What's the thermal resistance of a 1808? 
You may be looking at an array of these or something designed for the power instead.

I'm no high power RF engineer so let's hear from someone with practical experience.

You may find [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=19&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjs59vc6_bnAhUbi1wKHcVWAAsQFjASegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.ie%2Fpdfdocs%2FATC-rf_ceramic_caps_high_rf_ap.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1_-4I4m0ggdbNc0CR3XNnj) useful on rating RF capacitors. It reinforces that you really need to know the ESR at your operating frequency, and the

To match your rated ripple current, you may be looking at something more like [these from Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/doc?22086) though you don't need anything like their 7.5 kV DC rating.